# What is the difference between 何もありません and 何もあります?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

何もありません and  何もあります both have the same meaning according to google translate. I have no trouble in understanding why 何もありません has the meaning of "nothing/everything" as one of my native languages has a similar structure but 何もあります is what I have problems with.

How can a word when in the negative and positive form both give out the same meaning? Both according to google translate means "There is nothing". Is 何もあります even spoken much in day-to-day talks?

Comment: Do not use google translate for anything except to "feel" general idea of sentence. It often doesn't see nuances and sometimes completly ignore important parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

何もあります is a mistake. Google translate is not able to tell you whether a sentence is grammatically correct or not, so maybe it's just giving you its closest guess.

Note however that you *can* use it in a positive sense if you use でも instead of も.

- 何{なに}もありません = there is nothing
- 何{なん}でもあります = there is anything/everything

Also note the difference in the reading of the kanji "何" in these two cases.

Reference: [現代日本語文法概説：１６．疑問語・不定語](https://web.archive.org/web/20180318034313/http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/16gimongo.html) (section 16.2.1/16.2.2)