# Is「誰も知っている」 grammatical?

Tags: grammar, meaning

The above was recovered from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-%E8%AA%B0%E3%82%82-and-%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-in-Japanese).

---

> **(A)** 誰も知っている

I think this is wrong and が should be added.

> **(B)** 誰も**が**知っている

I cannot find a reputable source which explicitly says that **A** is wrong, but I've never seen it used that way either.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between 何なにもありません and 何もあります?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62253/43676)

Comment: @aguijonazo Is **A** wrong then?

Comment: Sentence (A) is wrong because 誰も is an NPI. Specifically, please read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010) answer.

Comment: @naruto Yes, I've read that post a while a go. I just wanted to make sure, thank you.